# How do I make sure that every new opportunity created starts on stage 1?

Tags: opportunity

I want to prevent opportunities being made retrospectively and created at closed won stage. How to I make each and every opportunity created start at Stage 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a **Validation rule** to prevent retroactive creation of the Opportunities [image]

```
ISNEW() && ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won')
```

Add an appropriate Error Condition Formula and Error Message to display when the validation rule fails.

After the above you can Create a before insert trigger to set the StageName to Stage 1 on the Opportunity Object for ensuring the new opportunity created start at Stage 1.

Use the following code as a starting point for your trigger:

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert) {
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        opp.StageName = 'Stage 1';
    }
}
```

With this approach, the validation rule will prevent Opportunities from being created retroactively with the Closed Won stage. The before insert trigger will automatically set the StageName to Stage 1 for all newly created Opportunities, ensuring they start at the desired stage.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to create a new Validation Rule on the Opportunity object.
You will need to check that the CreatedDate is now(ish) and that might be a little difficult to do in a formula.
Alternatively, you can create a trigger on the Opportunity object that fires on the Before Create event and will prevent creating new Opportunities that are not in stage 1.

For more information you can check out the [Trailhead module on validation rules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/validation_rules) or the [Trailhead module on triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers).

Comment: `ISNEW` detects if a record is new or not.